# Profiles are Universal or In-House, why is Xcode complaining that they need to be App Store?

Tags: applications, xcode, mac-appstore, ios

Okay, I am trying to resolve an issue where I am generating ipas but when I go to Validate App, it says re-sign the target that I generated the ipa for and specifically it says `needs to be re-signed for App Store distribution.`.

Yet the provisioning profile types created were created as **Universal or In-House** types. Why is it requiring it to be **App Store** distribution then?

What steps could I have done wrong in the archiving process?

[image]

It looks like I am grabbing an expired iOS Distribution, but if its also been under the type of Universal, would that make a difference?